# Regression Java Weka API

Tags: java, machine-learning, regression, weka, prediction

I have a test set and a training set and I should perform a numeric prediction of the class label using M5p. 
How it is possible to invoke m5p using java weka api? 
I tried this but I think that it doesn't work because I get values very high of rmse: 
("testSet" have class values equal to '0' while "testset" no)

```
M5P  predictor = new M5P (); 
predictor.buildClassifier(trainingSet); 
for (int i = 0; i < testSet.numInstances(); i++) 
{ 
   double pred = predictor.classifyInstance(testSet.instance(i)); 
   Attribute last = testSet.instance(i).classAttribute(); 
   testSet.instance(i).setValue(last, pred); 
   Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(testSet); 
   eval.evaluateModelOnce(pred, testset.instance(i));           
   double rmse = eval.rootMeanSquaredError();
```

}

If it is wrong can you advise me which instruction to use to make numerical prediction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [official](https://weka.wikispaces.com/file/view/M5PExample.java/82917117/M5PExample.java) example of using. Also, the same example is [described](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Numeric-Prediction-One-Day-Ahead-using-Weka-API-td40590.html).
About API you can see more [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/M5P.html).

Comment: What is a file .save?

Comment: Did you mean how to save results into the file?

Comment: No i don't know the extension ".save". Is there an editor that allows to open file .save?

Comment: You can use a simple text editor, I think. When it is a specific format, I think you can use WEKA environment.